# Using fb Messenger API in Python

Tags: python, facebook, curl, chatbot

I'm a complete beginner in both of Python and APIs things, I was trying to create a chatbot using Python using simple text response,the problem is I'm trying to use the FB documentation but it uses cURL and PHP "I think"

so how can I use the documenation code for example :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/template/button

the code in this link to fit in my code in Python

here is an example of my simple response which already works

```
if data['object'] == 'page':
    for entry in data['entry']:
        for messaging_event in entry['messaging']:

            # IDs
            sender_id = messaging_event['sender']['id']
            recipient_id = messaging_event['recipient']['id']

            if messaging_event.get('message'):
                # Extracting text message
                if 'text' in messaging_event['message']:
                    messaging_text = messaging_event['message']['text']
                else:
                    messaging_text = 'no text'

                # Echo
                response = None

                entity, value = wit_reponse(messaging_text)
                if entity == 'schedule':
                    response = "Ok I will send you {} news".format(str(value))
                elif entity == "location":
                    response = "Ok so you live in {0}. I will send you top headlines from {0}".format(str(value))

                if response == None:
                    response = "You know that I'm a bot at the end,I didn't understand :("

                bot.send_text_message(sender_id, response)
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question sorry. Your code appears to already be responding to a JSON response. Presumably you already got some output from the API to respond to. Why have you linked specifically to "Button Template Reference"?

Comment: @roganjosh I want to use Facebook different templates not my own text responses, but I can re-shape the facebook cURL code to Python 

more briefly : I want to use facebook templates in my chatbot but can't use it with python